# SSRS Return after ||

Tags: reporting-services, return

Currently the code is returning:

```
Row 1 accountNumber||locations=HLOB
Row 2 OrderLocation=HLPACU||OrderLocation=HLSS||OrderLocation=HLSSOVER
```

I'd like to see results as follows. Having a return after the "||"

```
Row 1 accountNumber
      locations=HLOB
Row 2 OrderLocation=HLPACU
      OrderLocation=HLSS
      OrderLocation=HLSSOVER
```

What is the correct expression to use in the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are multiple ways to do this,
one option is to use Split function. example as below

```
Split("String_tobe_splited","||",3)
```

The above expression splits the string whenever it sees "||" and forms an array of string for "3" substrings.

While using this array, if you want first substring you can call as  `Split("String_tobe_splited","_",3)(0)`

other option is to use Replace function as below

```
= Replace(String.Value,"||",vbCrLf)
```

one more option is, write a VB code to manipulate output string as you want.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. "= Replace(String.Value,"||",vbCrLf)"